# macOS 10.12 auto-layout issues

Tags: macos-sierra

There are several huge changes in 10.12, but in my opinion the biggest is the new auto-layout system (or modified/rewritten old one ... who knows). I have prepared a simple project to demonstrate the issue. It's related with collapsing a split view item via a button. It happens only on 10.12. All you need to do is to compile the project and click the button. An error will be presented:

> 2016-10-04 15:10:28.284296 test-12[64932:7425277] [Layout] Detected missing constraints for .  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.

After setting a breakpoint we can find out that the problematic view is:

```
(lldb) po $arg1
<NSSplitDividerView: 0x618000161980>
```

Am I completely wrong or there is a definite problem with 10.12? And please advice how to prevent such type of errors if possible.

The project can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/ivailon/test-12)

Once again thank you for the help.

I. Nikolov

Comment: I can trigger this message simply by calling NSAlert.layout() to force the alert to lay itself out immediately.  Since none of the suggestions work in this case and there is no obvious way to avoid the error, I filed a radar (rdar://28700495).

Comment: I remedy this issue by returning `false` from `splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, shouldHideDividerAt dividerIndex: Int) -> Bool` in my `NSSplitViewController`.

Comment: @LShi: Thanks I had the same problem and it worked for me too.

Comment: @LShi You should post your fix as an answer. It worked for me.

Comment: Hi, currently I don't use this "hack" in my project and there's no error any more. What's your macOS version? Mine is 10.13. When does this happen? At startup or upon toggling the splitviewitem/sidebar?

Comment: Yes - I can confirm that this issue is no longer present.

Comment: My app running on macOS 10.13 has a new problem: sometimes the divider of the splitview becomes a strange dash line after my sidebar is expanded(with animation). The trick presented above seemingly solves that problem.

Comment: Unfortunately 10.13 is .... kindly saying .... buggy

Answer (score 0):

I have the same auto-layout issue and I found a workaround for my project.
After adding the subview with its constrains I call the window to "layout". Unfortunately I do that after each "add" call, otherwise the system will throw the ugly message again. It works for me and I am just calling it during initialistion.

```
  // Left Split View
  [self.scrollviewMain setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  [self.viewMainLeft addSubview:self.scrollviewMain];
  [self.viewMainLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainLeft attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:l_floatConstant]];
  [self.viewMainLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainLeft attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    multiplier:1.0 constant:-l_floatConstant]];
  [self.viewMainLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainLeft attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft   multiplier:1.0 constant:-l_floatConstant]];
  [self.viewMainLeft addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainLeft attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewMain attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight  multiplier:1.0 constant:l_floatConstant]];
  [self.windowMain layoutIfNeeded];
  // Right Split View
  [self.scrollviewDetails setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  [self.viewMainRight addSubview:self.scrollviewDetails];
  [self.viewMainRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainRight attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:l_floatConstant]];
  [self.viewMainRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainRight attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop    multiplier:1.0 constant:-l_floatConstant-1]];
  [self.viewMainRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainRight attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft   multiplier:1.0 constant:-l_floatConstant]];
  [self.viewMainRight addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewMainRight attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollviewDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight  multiplier:1.0 constant:l_floatConstant]];
  [self.windowMain layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: But ... you should agree that this is not the right way of doing layout ... There is definitely something wrong ... or at least misinterpreted. Anyways - thank you for the info. There are several such workarounds, which in my opinion are not efficient neither sophisticated. Let's hope that things will change in the future or we will get more information how to prevent such situations.