# OS X NSAlert window won't close in xCode 8 in Objective-C

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode8, nsalert

I used the method below in xCode 7 to show alerts/errors.  I know alertWithMessageText is deprecated now.  If I use this method in xCode 8 (though deprecated), the window doesn't close when the user presses the Ok button. I have looked at dozens of posts to replace it with the beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler: method, but cannot get it to work. Some example code would be greatly appreciated.

( I get the following console message when I run the xCode 7 method:
2016-10-12 15:35:23.537072 eBuyBooks[7886:2192964] [Layout] Detected missing constraints for .  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.)

```
// in Header file
NSAlert * alertWithOkButton;
```

.....

```
// in implementation file
- (void)errorPopUp:(NSString *)reason detail:(NSString *)detail {

    alertWithOkButton = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:reason
                                        defaultButton:@"Ok"     
                                      alternateButton:nil       
                                          otherButton:nil       
                            informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@",detail];

    [alertWithOkButton runModal];    
}
```

Comment: `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` is a replacement for `runModal` and `runModal` isn't deprecated.

Comment: The replacement for `alertWithMessageText` is in the documentation: "Instead, alloc and init an NSAlert object and set its attributes as appropriate."

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a replacement, it is not deprecated:

```
// in implementation file
- (void)errorPopUp:(NSString *)reason detail:(NSString *)detail {
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:reason];
        [alert setInformativeText:detail];
        [alert setAlertStyle:NSCriticalAlertStyle]; // or NSWarningAlertStyle, or NSInformationalAlertStyle
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

        [alert runModal];
}
```

To set a symbolic breakpoint, go to the Breakpoint Navigator (little outline arrow at top left of your project window), click "+" at the bottom left of the window, select "Symbolic Breakpoint" and enter `DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS` for the symbol.

If the breakpoint gets hit, you can enter `po $arg1` in the debugger view to print the description of the view that misses the constraints.

Comment: Great!  Worked! Still get this console msg: `code`2016-10-14 16:06:13.664282 eBuyBooks[24614:6627678] [Layout] Detected missing constraints for <private>.  It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error will only be logged once.

Comment: Then I'd say this error comes from somewhere else. Try to set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS, like the error says.

Comment: The message occurs when [alert run modal] line executes. In trying to figure out how to place a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS, I saw Apple tech note: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html.  It is very long and involved and I cannot figure out how to place the breakpoint.  Further, is it likely to just point at the NSAlert window?  If so, I have also scoured the NSAlert documentation on any properties or methods that might resolve this constraint issue.  I tried several, including initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(...) but none resolved the error message.

Comment: I added information on how to set the breakpoint to my answer. But this problem might be a macOS 10.12 bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852109/macos-10-12-auto-layout-issues

Comment: Dirk, thanks for the info on symbolic breakpoints.  (Good new tool for me. I only knew you could set a breakpoint on a line of code.) I set it and the result is "<NSTextField: 0x6100001e0a00>" which I am guessing is one of the text fields on the NSAlert window that is setup by the new auto layout mentioned in the StackOverflow item you mentioned. Since the warning doesn't seem to cause any bad behavior, I guess I will just ignore it and see if Apple fixes it.

Comment: I found the problem!  I was passing in a NULL NSString pointer to the detail argument ([alert setInformativeText:detail].  That was drawing the constraints warning.  The clue was after I breakpointed DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS, I saw in the stack trace that the last line was an error on an NSTextField and figured auto layout created the necessary NSTextFields.

Comment: Hi rick, here also happen if you set a zero length [alert setInformativeText:@""], so the string must be at least 1 char long to avoid logging the error. Thanks